# Passing strings through embed in ExpressionEngine for Raphael library use

Tags: javascript, html, embed, raphael, expressionengine

So for those of you familiar with the ExpressionEngine CMS, you know that when you embed code, you can {embed="site/header" dog_name="Shadow"} and then within the embed, call the parameter (i.e...

```
<div><h2> - My dog's name is {embed:dog_name} </h2> </div>
```

However, when I try to apply the same principle to this embed it fails:

```
<div id="graphicLinks"> 
    {embed="in-store-analytics/retail-analytic" quote="Hello"} 
</div>
```

Passing to...

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var p = Raphael("graphicLinks", 300, 50);

 var quote = {embed:quote};

// Creates an object group
 p.setStart();
 var contactRect= p.rect(0, 0, 120, 45);
 var contactText = p.text(11,22,quote);
```

There is more code, but I only included the relevant parts.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** OK So I just debugged a little, and I found out that the element does in fact get passed. However, the html doesn't recognize the element:

```
window.onload = function() {
var p = Raphael("graphicLinks", 300, 50);
var quote = Hello;
```

The java console says, "*ReferenceError: Hello is not defined*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to quote the variable:

```
 var quote = "{embed:quote}";
```

That should do it.

Comment: THANK YOU! Though I'm not sure why it wouldn't get passed as a string to begin with.

Comment: Embed variables *are* passed as strings, but not as *quoted* strings. Important difference!

Comment: Also make sure you are not using user-submitted information in this way (wrapping in quotes), as a malicious user could add their own quotes to the text and cause an XSS attack on your site. User data would need to be correctly encoded as a Javascript string.